# laravel error when I ran it on terminal in macos

Tags: laravel, macos

when I ran `laravel` in my terminal it's not working, I already added the path to my bash_profile I am using MacOS. Valet is working I dont know what happened if it is from the installation or not.

this is the returned error:

```
    PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Laravel\Installer\Console\NewCommand' not found in /Users/mycomputer/.composer/vendor/laravel/installer/laravel:11
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /Users/mycomputer/.composer/vendor/laravel/installer/laravel on line 11

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Laravel\Installer\Console\NewCommand' not found in /Users/mycomputer/.composer/vendor/laravel/installer/laravel:11
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /Users/mycomputer/.composer/vendor/laravel/installer/laravel on line 11
```

Comment: try upgrading the Laravel installer in case you are running an older version, you can do that using:

composer global update laravel/installer

Comment: Thanks @Collin it worked!